# Programmatically turn off VoiceProcessingIO AGC

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I'm using Apple's CoreAudio framework for recording my microphone feed. Automatic Gain Control seems to be enabled by default: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AudioUnitPropertiesReference/Reference/reference.html

```
kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingEnableAGC
Indicates whether automatic gain control is enabled (any nonzero value) or disabled (a value of 0). Automatic gain control is enabled by default.
Value is a read/write UInt32 valid on the global audio unit scope.
Available in OS X v10.7 and later.
Declared in AudioUnitProperties.h.
```

How do I programmatically turn off the AGC in CoreAudio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're using an AUVoiceProcessor Audio Unit called `voiceProcessor`

```
UInt32 turnOff = 0;
AudioUnitSetProperty(voiceProcessor,
                     kAUVoiceIOProperty_VoiceProcessingEnableAGC,
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global,
                     0,
                     &turnOff,
                     sizeof(turnOff));
```

Quick explanation: What this is doing is setting a *property* on the audio unit to 0, which in this case disables the AGC. Audio Units typically have two sets of controllable values called *properties* and *parameters*. You can set/get these values by using `AudioUnitSetProperty()` / `AudioUnitGetProperty()` and `AudioUnitSetParameter()` / `AudioUnitGetParameter()` accordingly.

Note: You should probably check the `OSStatus` code that `AudioUnitSetProperty()` returns (it'll be equal to `noErr` if there wasn't an error).

Comment: `AudioUnitSetProperty` is deprecated, any other way? https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiounit/1653800-audio_unit_component_services ?

Comment: @zevarito I'm not seeing that it's deprecated, but nonetheless this fails for me - returning OSStatus `k​Audio​Unit​Err_Invalid​Property`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this still the only post addressing this? Still pulling hair on this problem in 2021. Anyone?